# C++ regex example outputs differ from the official

Tags: c++, regex, clang, c++14, linux-mint

Following code fragment is from [cppreference#regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "
        "\"I know, I'll use regular expressions.\" "
        "Now they have two problems.";

    std::regex self_regex("REGULAR EXPRESSIONS",
            std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::icase);
    if (std::regex_search(s, self_regex)) {
        std::cout << "Text contains the phrase 'regular expressions'\n";
    }

    std::regex word_regex("(\\S+)");
    auto words_begin = 
        std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), word_regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    std::cout << "Found "
              << std::distance(words_begin, words_end)
              << " words\n";

    const int N = 6;
    std::cout << "Words longer than " << N << " characters:\n";
    for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        std::string match_str = match.str();
        if (match_str.size() > N) {
            std::cout << "  " << match_str << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::regex long_word_regex("(\\w{7,})");
    std::string new_s = std::regex_replace(s, long_word_regex, "[$&]");
    std::cout << new_s << '\n';
}
```

It compiles well, but the output is different from the example page where I copied from:

```
Text contains the phrase 'regular expressions'
Found 0 words
Words longer than 6 characters:
Some [people,] when [confronted] with a [problem,] think "I know, I'll use [regular] [expressions."] Now they have two [problems.]
```

Which should be:

```
Text contains the phrase 'regular expressions'
Found 19 words
Words longer than 6 characters:
  people,
  confronted
  problem,
  regular
  expressions."
  problems.
Some people, when [confronted] with a [problem], think 
"I know, I'll use [regular] [expressions]." Now they have two [problems].
```

My laptop info:

> Linux 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My compiler info:

> clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
>   Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   Thread model: posix

What causes the difference? compiler version?

What should I do to make it work correctly?

Comment: Can't reproduce with clang-6.0 on my machine.

Comment: @Johnllacqua Also thanks

Comment: It may also matters much which of libc++ and libstdc++ is used as stdlib.